# Is this the fastest way to create a large list of model instances in Django that require an id lookup for a ForeignKey field?

Tags: python, django

Models

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
    # ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    # ...
```

Is this the fastest way to create new instances of Bar given a list of Foo names? Or is there a way you can use foo's name in the creation of the Bar instance?

```
    to_create = []
    for name in names:
        try:
            foo = Foo.objects.only('id').get(name=name).id
        except Foo.DoesNotExist:
            continue
        to_create.append(Bar(foo=foo, *other_fields))

    Bar.objects.bulk_create(to_create)
```

Comment: you may be able to increase the speed slightly by setting `Foo.objects.only('id')` as a variable outside of the for loop (reducing the dot operators in the for loop). Besides that using list comprehension may speed up the for loop.

Comment: Doesnt seem to make a difference with .only outside the loop.  Sorry can you give an example of what you mean by list comprehension?

Comment: Do you mean throw all the logic into the creation of the to_create list instead of appending to it? e.g to_create = [Foo(DBQuery[name]) for name in names] type thing?

Comment: Yes that is list comprehension https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: The only way I can think to implement that while still handling cases where Foo does not exist requires an extra db call so it is a bit slower.  Since I can't store the db call for Foo in a variable within the list comprehension

Comment: why not do `to_create = [Bar(foo=foo.id, *other_fields) for name in names if foo := Foo.objects.only('id').get(name=name)]`

Comment: Ah I didn't realise you could create variables in list comprehension like that.  Still seems the same though, I had to pull out the Foo.get into its own method though so I can handle the DoesNotExist (essentially get_or_none_if_does_not_exist).  Not sure if that makes a big difference.  Thanks for teachming me := though